# How to decide the order of components added to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextpane

I have a JPanel of null layout called MainPanel. Onclick of a button I am adding JTextpane on mainPanel. On first click I am creating a textpane of background color white. On second click I am creating another textpane of color blue. What I want is to place the blue textpane upon the white textpane, but the blue textpane is going behind the white textpane. How can I place it on white pane?

Code is very simple here. Onclick I am creating a new JTextpane, setting dimensions to it and placing it on the mainPanel.

Placing a sample screenshot which describes the issue better. Here the blue textpane has gone behind white textpane. I want it above white texpane. How do I do that?
[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you showed the code.

Comment: 14 question asked. Not a single answer accepted so I'm not going to waste my time answering when the effort is not appreciated. Only comment is don't use a null layout!!!

Answer (score 2):

*If you want to stick with your current Components*, (I think you should use kellax's solution, but I don't know if there's an extra requirement that's forcing you to use your current approach) you can look into Container.setComponentZOrder(Component comp, int index) to directly determine the order in which Components are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to replace your `JPanel "MainPanel"` with a `LayeredPanel`.

Then you can say:

```
JLayeredPane mainPanel = new JLayeredPane();

JTextPane whitePane = new JTextPane("White text pane on top");
JTextPane bluePane  = new JTextPane("Blue text pane behind");

mainPanel.add(whitePane, 2, 0);
mainPanel.add(bluePane, 1, 0);
```

Edit:
You can read more about the LayeredPane here: [LayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Comment: I corrected my code a bit i declared `JLayeredPane` as `mainPanel` but then called `pane.add` Should be correct now.

Comment: That's fine. I replaced JPanel with Layered pane in my code and it works perfectly now. Thanks a lot :)